# Downloads SVG from link to file fails as not valid base64?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to download an SVG image it looks like base64 but fails. The URL is a lot longer than this but I shortened it for veiwers sake.

> data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%0A%3Csvg%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20height%3D%2232%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20320%20320%22%20wid3A%20%20%3Crect%20height%3D%22320%22%20id%3D%22rect%22%20rx%3D%2251.2%22%20width%3D%22320%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CclipPath%20id%3D%22clip%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22%23rect%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FclipPath%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fdefs%3E%0A%20%20%3Cuse%20fill%3D%22%23FFFC00%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-

Code:

```
foreach (var username in File.ReadAllLines("/Users/admin/Desktop/snap-scraper/snap-scraper/snapchats.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to grab QR for {username}");

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"https://snapchat.com/add/{username}");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);

    var image = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img");

    if (image == null || !image.Attributes.Contains("src"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong for {username}");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Got the QR for {username} yay");

    var src = image.Attributes.Where(x => x.Name == "src").First().Value;

    string filePath = $"/Users/admin/Desktop/snap-scraper/snap-scraper/images/{username}.jpg";
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(src.Replace("-", "")));
}
```

Comment: That is URL-encoded, not base64-encoded.  `...it looks like base64...`  No it doesn't; base64-encoded strings do not contain `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `Base64`. It's `URL Encoding`. You can see this in a [URL Decoder Tool](https://urldecode.org/) if you paste in the encoded URL.

Since SVG's are made up of an `XML format` they do not require encoding.

You can use [WebUtility.UrlDecode(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8) to decode the string and then convert it to bytes using [Encoding.GetBytes(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8) write the bytes to disk.

Example:

```
foreach (var username in File.ReadAllLines("/Users/admin/Desktop/snap-scraper/snap-scraper/snapchats.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to grab QR for {username}");

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"https://snapchat.com/add/{username}");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);

    var image = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img");

    if (image == null || !image.Attributes.Contains("src"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong for {username}");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Got the QR for {username} yay");

    var src = image.Attributes.Where(x => x.Name == "src").First().Value;

    string filePath = $"/Users/admin/Desktop/snap-scraper/snap-scraper/images/{username}.svg"; // This was .jpg

    // URL Decode Image - Remember to strip the start of the data url e.g. data:image/svg xml;utf8,
    string svg = WebUtility.UrlDecode(src).replace("data:image/svg xml;utf8,", "");

    // Convert SVG to byte array
    byte[] svgBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedUrl);

    // Write to byte array to disk
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, svg);
}
```

Comment: `UrlDecode` returns a string, how do I get a `byte[]` from that?

Comment: Byte arrays shouldn't be url-encoded.  Find the string's encoding and use the `GetBytes()` method of the encoder.  You would be better off base64 encoding the value, though.

Comment: @LeeNelson Updated answer. It's just linking you to the Microsoft Docs for Encoding.GetBytes(string)

Comment: @Riddell Linking to the docs is good, but the essential parts of your answer should be in the answer in case those links go dead.

Comment: Attempting to download it with `File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(WebUtility.UrlDecode(src)));` but it seems to be a corrupt image. When attempting to open it, my MacBook says its empty.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I am now getting a "Could not open file" error saying it could be damaged.

Comment: @LeeNelson it's because you're writing `svg` to disk as `.jpg` and svg extension is `.svg`. Not only that but you don't need to convert to bytes as it's unnecessary.  I've updated code snippet to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198897/discussion-between-riddell-and-lee-nelson).